# Implement Floyed Rivest

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio, oop

How can you implement a online floyed rivest in c#

The commented code is the part which I have not manged to implement

So far what I Implemented is:

.

```
  protected int Select(int[] array, int left, int right, int k)
    {
        while (right > left)
        {
            if(right-left>600)
            {
                int n = right - left + 1;
                int x = k - left + 1;
                //int z=ln(n)
               //int s= 0.5 *exp(2 * z / 3)
                //int sd = 0.5 * sqrt(z * s * (n - s) / n) * sign(x - n / 2)
                //int newLeft = max(left, k - x * s / n + sd)
                //int newRight = min(right, k + (n - x) * s / n + sd)

            }
            int t = array[k];
            int i = left;
            int j = right;
            Swap(array, left, k);
            if(array[right]>t)
            {
                Swap(array, right, left);
            }
            while(i<j)
            {
                Swap(array, i, j);
                i = i + 1;
                j = j - 1;
                while(array[i]<t)
                {
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                while (array[j] > t)
                {
                    j = j - 1;
                }
            }
            if(array[left]==t)
            {
                Swap(array, left, j);
            }
            else
            {
                j = j + 1;
                Swap(array, j, right);
            }
            if(j<=k)
            {
                left = j + 1;
            }
            if(k<=j)
            {
                right = j - 1;
            }
        }

    }
    public void Swap(this int[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
```

Is the implementation correct?

How can I implement the commented code?

Comment: For the mathematical functions,use the `System.Math` class. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: and put the result that you get in double (not int)